# Why Qt4 doesn't scale fonts smoothly?

Tags: fonts, scaling

In Qt4.8, I have QFont object with font "verdana", that is used for the QGraphicsTextItem, drawn on QGraphicsView. I also have QSlider that smoothly changes the size of the font using QFont::setPointSizeF.

What I observe is that text, represented by QGraphicsTextItem, doesn't scale smoothly. Instead, it changes in jumps, occurring around integer values of the (qreal) scaling factor. There are also some gradual, smaller modifications between these jumps at the integer points.

I think, Qt uses libfreetype.so to render fonts. And font in use is verdana.ttf, which is obviously the TrueType font. It is a vector font, and theoretically can be scaled smoothly.

So why text doesn't change smoothly with scaling factor? Why integer points matter?

I was expecting to see the font modification like in Android: when user scales the window, all  fonts grow nicely and smoothly.
Why this isn't the same with Qt's QFont/libfreetype?

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour at larger point sizes? Typically fonts use optimised bitmap images for characters at smaller points sizes (because vector doesn't provide very good results or take a lot of time to generate). It sounds like you're seeing QT using these bitmaps and then scaling them up slightly. It would make sense that you see this on desktop systems where there is room to keep caches and not on tablets / phones where space comes at a premium...

Comment: I observe this up to the the large sizes, around 60. Any way to prevent this optimization, avoid these fixed bitmaps and do pure vector rendering?

Comment: Depends how smart the operating system is :) Is it possible to try slightly rotating (not multiples of 90%) or skewing the text?

Comment: This isn't really about the smarts of OS, this is about the smarts of FreeType library most likely. I wonder if there is some option to disable this. Or, on the other hand, this might be just a manifestation of some bug.

Comment: You might be correct, but I know that as far back as Mac OS 8.x (yes, that's without the "X" in it :)), the operating system was capable of providing optimised bitmaps for TrueType fonts. I know because I used them while writing a PostScript rendering engine and this was the only way to get legible text... I would guess that a library like FreeType (that I'm unfamiliar with just to be complete) would try to take advantage of such "free" information. But my original suggestion stands whichever way you look at it I think.